# Need to create an XML Data Source

Tags: php, xml, lithium

I tried following the manual on creating a custom data source but since the XML data source will be a file system data source, I'm not sure how to proceed.

The problem is that the types available are database, mongo, and http service. I can't really configure the model to pull from XML because there is no XML or filesystem data source type.

Here is a link to the manual: http://li3.me/docs/manual/working-with-data/creating-data-sources.wiki

Comment: Please add a link to the manual you talk about. This might make it more clear what you ask about.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you would have to use the [PHP File IO](http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/php/fileIO.html) stuff. And I'm sure PHP also provides a means to work with XML. You could do this in the context of creating a custom data source. The instructions look pretty clear.

(In response to your comment) - I understood your original question and found the section on creating data sources. You are going to still need to use the PHP stuff to access files and XML if you create your own data source. Then you can use the data source as part of the rest of your app. I don't see anyway around this since they don't provide the data source you want.

Comment: Sorry, I reread my question and noticed it wasn't clear about what framework I was using. I am asking about Lithium Framework. Specifically, I want to be able to access my XML records through the model system they have in the framework.

Comment: Your question was clear from the tags, I looked up the doc on the Lithium framework, I expanded my answer a little.

Comment: Looks like there still is a little miscommunication. I meant that I'm not sure how to create the interface so that the models will automagically be populated based off of the XML data I give it. I can easily use something like simpleXML to pull data in at the Model level or at the Controller level. I don't want to do that. I want to be able to do  Model::All($query) and have my model populated.